# Ubuntu rename Wi-Fi to "eth0"

Tags: networking, network-manager, udev

I need to install a software (iCEcube2 from Lattice Semiconductor) on a Ubuntu 20.04 machine. Apparently there is something hardcoded in this software related to license checking that requires the computer to be connected to the internet via a connection with name "eth0" ([link](https://vhdlwhiz.com/lattice-icecube2-ubuntu-20-04-icestick/)). I have tried creating the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` with the following content

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="eth0"
```

where `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` is actually my MAC address. After this I restarted the computer. It does not work. I also tried the method described in [the link before](https://vhdlwhiz.com/lattice-icecube2-ubuntu-20-04-icestick/) under the title *License checkout failed: hostid of this system does not match the hostid*.

The option *1.* in [this SO answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400898/317682), i.e. `sudo ip link set wlp2s0 name eth0` works, however it is temporal.

Comment: [this is a different reference](https://www.xmodulo.com/change-network-interface-names-permanently-linux.html) does it help?

Comment: Is this a server or desktop install?  Are you using Network Manager to manage the wifi device and connections?

Answer (score 1):

On the TinyFPGA forum it is suggested to use 2 lines, not 1:

> Going through the interface issue
>
> Lattice iCEcube2 license takes into account the MAC address of the computer. In order to work, the interface must be labeled as eth0.

```
sudo ip link add eth0 type dummy
sudo ip link set eth0 address {mac}
```

where `ip link show` can be used to show what {mac} needs to be what is shown at the name it is shown now for your NIC.

> however it is temporal.

If they are temporary your settings are likely rewritten by networkmanager, a dhcp server, dhclient, and/or another tool. You would need to disable that

or

you could add those 2 lines to `/etc/crontab`.